# Reading until space

Tags: shell, unix, sed

I want to read the second line of a file:

```
$(sed -n 2p $file)
```

This works pretty well, but I want to read the line **only** until the very first space.
Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: are you using the $(...) command substitution for a reason? normally we'd see myDate="$(sed ... file)". Good luck.

Comment: Have added an alternate solution without using pipes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
$ sed -n 2p $file | cut -d " " -f1
```

Comment: Do you have the same solution for a tab character? `cat x.txt | cut -d "\t" -f1` says `delimiter must be a single character` Edit: I should have searched more first: `cut -d$'\t' -f 1` from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/35370/187185

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try something like this:

```
$(sed -n '2s/ .*//p' $file)
```

It's like yours, except the `s` command substitutes a space and anything after it (`.*`) with nothing, i.e. removes the rest of the line.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to split your line in an array and then read it one word at a time.

```
while IFS=" " read -a word; do # storing the line separated by space in an array 
    echo "${word[0]}"; # calling the first array element which is indexed at 0
done < <(head -n 2 file | tail -n 1) # process substitution of fetching only second line
```

**Test:**

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat file
a  212
b  323
c  23
d  45
e  54
f  102

[jaypal:~/Temp] while IFS=" " read -a word; do 
echo "${word[0]}"; 
done < <(head -n 2 file | tail -n 1)
b
```

Alternatively, if you just want a quick solution with a one-liner then the following will work just fine -

```
awk 'NR==2{print $1}' filename
```

**Test:**

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] awk 'NR==2{print $1}' file
b
```